# Why browser redirect whe attempting to set the value of Wordpress media image alt field?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bookmarklet

I am trying to write a bookmarklet to populate the Wordpress image gallery manager, clicking an image pops up the sidbar with these fields,there are alt (input), legend,and description, both are textarea.
my Js snippet is:

```
<a href="javascript:var t=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar label input');var a=t[2];var u=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar textarea');var b=u[0];var v=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar label input');var c=u[1];a.value='Hello';">Duplicate</a>
```

When I click the link, i am redirected to a new page, with the text i want to set. How to do it correctly, i don't know why i am being redirected. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `onClick` event?

Comment: @Justinas — They said they were writing a bookmarklet. That has to be a URL.

Comment: I tried this solution which didnt work in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008841/javascript-works-as-bookmarklet-but-not-as-onclick-link but thanks for suggesting this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `this.stop;` in the last of your `href`
And also use `a.innerHTML` because the variable `a` will be holding the `div` element which doesn't support `value` attribute/property.

```
<a href="javascript:var t=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar label input');var a=t[2];var u=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar textarea');var b=u[0];var v=document.querySelectorAll('div.media-sidebar label input');var c=u[1];a.innerHTML='Hello';this.stop;">Duplicate</a>
```

This will stop the default behaviour of href and exit from redirecting to the new document.

Comment: i was using return false which did not work, this.stop works thank you

Comment: yes tried it also, it works thanks! (void 0)